# Application runs very slow in debug mode

Tags: c#, performance, debugging, visual-studio-2013

My C# program should execute an asynchronous task 30 times per second.

The program performs well as a standalone windows application.

But when it runs in debug mode in Visual Studio 2013 Professional environment the perfomance is very poor - just 5 tasks per second, even if there're no breakpoints in the code whatsoever.

Is slow debugging a "feature" of the VS.Net 2013 and is there a way to debug time critical C# apps?

Comment: You stated that it runs slow in Debug mode, but nothing else. Does it run faster in a Release build, but still under the debugger? What about a Debug build run directly (outside of VS)?

Comment: There have been some known reports of this. First, update your graphics card driver (yes, this can be a problem). Secondly, are you running Windows 8.1? if so - there are also certain known problems there too with IE11

Comment: The perfomance is same poor in Release under debugging. But when I start the program without debugging it's ok. The task does heavy calculations so the graphic card is no problem. And my computer runs under Win 7 Prof. Debug build outside of VS runs also ok.

Comment: One thing that can cause enormous slowdowns is the exception logging. Check in the output window if exceptions are being logged.

Comment: There are no exceptions in the log, however the program does a lot of logging using log4Net library. The logging is a required feature and works ok without debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Thank You **user1720293** for the idea about logging. The main reason for the huge perfomance drop was in logging to console through `log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender`. After commenting out a line in the configuration file the problem has gone

```
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <!-- here's the source of the problem
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    -->
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
  </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try eliminating a few things by:
Removing all watch items
Hiding the locals, autos window etc

Are you tracing out a lot of text? You could also try not doing that and see if it makes a difference.

Is visual studio left alone by your anti-virus software?

If it isn't pure c# code and c++ is involved anywhere then debugging performance is poor.

None of this is Visual Studio 13 specific advice.
Did you previously run this code ok on 2012 or 2010?

Comment: Cut off logging, the perfomance in debug mode JUMPED UP to 16 tasks per second, amazing, what does log4net library have to do with such debugging perfomance drop and why it doesn't affect perfomance of a stand alone application?

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you are using log4net heavily. If you are printing to the output stream each time you log, this will cause bad performance.

Console output is *always* slow. Consider using pre-processors to cherry pick the logging that you desire.

```
#if HEAVY_LOGGING_MODE
//log log log
#endif
```

Log4Net may support a better mechanism. Check the docs!

Answer (score 0):

Lot of breakpoints in code could effect the performance on debug mode.
Please try remove useless breakpoints.

Comment: actually, this is not true. you can have breakpoints as many as you like but will certainly not slow the performance of the IDE as reported. Furthermore the user reported even if there are hardly any breakpoints, same problem

Comment: If there are breakpoints with conditions, where the condition is never true, that will certainly slow down the program when executing through the debugger. Probably not pertinent in this case, but still.